# Using getopts and ${1} together

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm trying to write a script that can use both ${1} and getopts options simultaneously. I would like it to work using the usage line:

```
./test_script test -a
```

to print:

```
test
-a was triggered!
```

I've tried

```
echo ${1};

while getopts "c:a" opt; do
      case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    esac
done
```

Which is not able to give me access to both ${1} and detect that the -a option was used simultaneously. Is there a way to use both of these? I'd like to avoid turning the test string into another getopts option.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You have access to `$1` and you are able to detect that `-a` was passed to the script. So what exactly are you *not* able to do?

Comment: I don't have access to both. With the script above, if I do ./test_script test -a, the output is just "test" ... if I do ./test_script -a test the output is "-a\n-a was triggered!" ... I want the output "test\n-a was triggered!"

Comment: Your problem would appear to be that `getopts` stops after the first non-option. Meaning `./test_script -a test` works fine, but `./test_script test -a` doesn't... The `getopts` man page says this: `Any of the following shall identify the end of options: the special option "--", finding an argument that does not begin with a '-', or encountering an error.`

Comment: Note that the behavior @twalberg describes is standard (as far as there is a standard) shell command syntax: the options precede regular arguments. Some commands allow options to go after regular argument, but this is nonstandard.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *shift* when getopts exit.
For example:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    while getopts "c:a" opt ; do
        case $opt in
            # YOUR OPTIONS
        esac
    done

    OTHER_VALUE=$1
    shift
done
```

PS: usually I don't use getopts, but I prefer to parse the args by myself as following:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case "$1" in
        '-a' | '--along' ) 
            echo '-a was triggered' ;;
        '-b' | '--blong' ) 
            echo '-b was trigger with arg ' $2 ; 
            shift ;; # One extra shift for the argumnent $2
        * ) 
            echo 'Unknown value (maybe test)' ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```